# Derive worst case error inputs for floating addition/multiplication

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods, floating-point, error-propagation, rounding-error

It is well know the following floating point model

$$
fl(x \;op\; y) = \left( x \;op\; y \right)(1+\delta), |\delta| \leq u = 2^{-t-1}
$$

(section 2.2. formula 2.4. of [this book](http://servidor.demec.ufpr.br/CFD/bibliografia/Higham_2002_Accuracy%20and%20Stability%20of%20Numerical%20Algorithms.pdf)).

Just because I want to understand if there's already some study about it or not. Is there a well known constructive proof that could eventually shows for the specific case of addition and multiplication a proposition like

$$
\forall x \in F \exists y\in F : \left| \frac{fl(x \;op\; y) - x \;op\; y}{x \;op\; y} \right|=u
$$

Is there any reference about it? If not is there a simple counter example?

Comment: I think you are asking how to construct hard-to-round cases that are very close to a tie case for the IEEE-754 round-to-nearest-or-even mode? Since there is typically hardware support for addition and multiplication, it is not so interesting a problem, but people have published papers on [division](http://www.acsel-lab.com/arithmetic/arith15/papers/ARITH15_McFearin.pdf) and [simple math functions](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/TMDworstcases.pdf) which may require software solutions.

Comment: On second thought, maybe you are trying to construct test cases for basic floating-point operations, along the lines of [this paper](http://research.ibm.com/haifa/projects/verification/fpgen/papers/Arith17-InvisibleBits.pdf)?

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the question as follows. In IEEE-754 floating-point arithmetic with a rounding mode of "to nearest or even", the result of a basic arithmetic operation will differ from the infinitely precise result by no more than half an ulp, that is the error is $\le \frac{1}{2} ulp$. For addition and multiplication, are there pairs of floating-point operands $a, b$ for which the error in $a\space{op}\space b$ is *exactly* $\frac{1}{2} ulp$?

The error is exactly $\frac{1}{2} ulp$ if the result falls exactly on the half-way point between two representable floating-point numbers. This is known as a tie case. It is easily shown that such cases exists for both addition and multiplication my manual construction:

$(1-ulp)+0.5$ is a tie case resulting from addition, while $(1-2ulp)*1.5$ is a tie case resulting from multiplication. In programming languages like C and C++ operands like $(1-ulp)$ can easily be constructed with the `nextafter()`, `nextafterf()` functions, if one desires a practical test.

The question remains, can one give a *general* algorithm that generates pairs of operands resulting in tie cases? The question is relevant to generation of test vectors for new floating-point hardware, for example. Traditionally, such verification relied on canned test vectors, such as [Jerome Coonen's collection](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/email/msg03098.html) of (presumably) manually constructed cases. More recently, there have been publications advocating an algorithmic approach, e.g.:

Merav Aharoni, et al. "Solving constraints on the invisible bits of the intermediate result for floating-point verification." In *Proceedings 17th IEEE Symposium on Computer Arithmetic (ARITH'05)*. IEEE 2005, pp. 76-83 ([online](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.324.4032&rep=rep1&type=pdf))

The invisible bits mentioned in the paper's title refer to the round and sticky bits prior to rounding, where for tie cases we would impose the constraints that the round bit be $1$ and the sticky bit be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

If that equation is the only thing you have, then there is nothing that you can do. On the other hand, if you use IEEE 754 floating point operations with standard rounding, then any result x in the range $2^k ≤ x ≤ 2^{k+1}$ will be rounded to the nearest multiple of $2^k · u$, and you can find the maximum relative error from that.

Comment: Yes you can assume we use IEEE754. But I don't get your explanation, can you elaborate a little bit more? I'm not sure if I was clear enough, but I'm not interested in the worst case error itself but how to describe the floating point inputs that make me achieve such error.

Comment: If an operation like a + b has a mathematical result x, and 2^k ≤ x ≤ 2^(k+1), then the result that you get is x rounded to the nearest multiple of 2^k * u. The inputs are quite irrelevant; it's the result of the operation that's interesting.

Comment: I don't understand why you're saying the inputs are irrelevant, because what I want to is to analyze the form of the inputs for which the max error is attained.

Comment: With one operation you will have difficulties realizing outrageous errors. It is constructions like $(1+x)-1$ where catastrophic cancellations occur.